# Add markers to given values of x in a plot

Tags: r, plot, spline

I am working with spline functions and I want to plot the basis and add markers showing the position of the knots. I've tried adding a vertical line using `abline(v=knots)` but the result is not nice and if I am dealing with many knots it's quite distracting.
I leave you an image below that shows what I want to do.
This is my code where I use the `bs` function from the package `splines`.

```
library(splines)
x <- seq(0, 1, length.out=1000)  
B <- bs(x, knots=seq(0, 1, length=20)[-c(1, 20)], Boundary.knots=c(0, 1), degree=2) 
matplot(x, B, type="l", lty=1, col="red")
```

This is what I would like to obtain (see those little "x" showing the position of the knots?). This is merely an example, if you have some idea to show the position of the knots in such a way that the result is non visually messy I would be glad to hear it.
[image]

I really appreciate any help

Comment: Just to be sure, you mean the little marks along the bottom (x axis) of the image?

Comment: Indeed those little "x". Actually this is just an example, they could be triangles or dots or any other kind of marker, what is important to me is that those should not interfere with the graph of the functions (that are not very friendly by their own)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, store the knot values from the attributes of `B`. And then use the low-level graphics function `points()` to add markers which the symbol can be adjusted by the argument `pch`.

```
knot <- c(0, attr(B, "knots"), 1)
points(knot, rep(0, length(knot)), pch = "x")
```

[image]

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for. Thanks